# Class<SomeObject<?>> is NOT a superclass of Class<SomeObject<SpecificObject>>?

Tags: java, generics

EDIT 1: According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html), despite `SomeObject<?>` being indeed a superclass of `SomeObject<Foo>`, `Class<SomeObject<?>>` is NOT a superclass of `Class<SomeObject<Foo>>`. The question on how to tackle this specific problem still persists. (adding a method to the `Message<T>` class that returns `Class<Message<T>>`, perhaps?)

Original question:

So basically I have a generic `Message<T>` class that implements a well known design pattern called [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (with a twist: instead of building an object with a reference, the reference is passed as argument of the `execute(T objectToCallMethodsOn)`) and it looks something like this:

```
public abstract class Message<T> {
    void execute(T obj); //e.g. DoSomethingOnFooMessage implements Message<Foo> to do something on a Foo object
}
```

so that I can do something like:

```
public DoSomethingOnFooMessage implements Message<Foo> {
    @Override
    void execute(Foo obj) {
        obj.doSomething(); //doSomething is a method of the Foo class
    }
}
```

Now, I also tried to make a MessageProcessor class with an internal map that maps (E is a type parameter) `Class<Message<E>>` to a object `E executableObject` (like Foo in the previous example) and with two methods: a handleMessage(Message<?> msg) that should do a dynamic instanceof of the Message (hence the need for the Class<> objects that let you do a dynamic instanceof and then a dynamic cast) and look for the right executableObject in the map to call the message's `execute(E obj)` on the right object (if it exists, otherwise the message is discarded), and a `addProcessor()` to add entries of e.g. `Class<Message<Foo>>, Foo` to the map:

```
public class MessageProcessor {
    private final Map<Class<Message<?>>, Object> map;

    public MessageProcessor() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public <E> void addProcessor(Class<Message<E>> messageClass, E executable) {
        map.put(messageClass, executable);
    }
    ...
}
```

So far that's what I wrote but the IDE complains that `Class<Message<E>>` was given but `Class<Message<?>>` was needed in `addProcessor()` and I don't know why; afaik, `SomeClass<?>` should be a superclass of any `SomeClass<SpecificClass>`, why isn't it the same for `Class<SomeObject<?>>` and `Class<SomeObject<SpecificObject>>`?

Sorry for the verbose question, other than asking a thing about superclassing of generics, I am also asking you guys for (perhaps) a different, more elegant way to do what I'm trying to do, which is find the runtime class of the message so that I can call its `execute()` with the object that I registered with the `addProcessor()` as its input.

Also, I reckon this could be easily solvable with raw types (ew)

Comment: "afaik, SomeClass<?> should be a superclass of any SomeClass<SpecificClass>" it most certainly shouldn't, what made you think that? `?` is "anything" not "anything in the class hierarchy chain from Object down to your specific class".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans isn't Object the superclass of every class by design? Also this page says so: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Comment: Try defining the map as.
`Map<Class<? extends Message<?>>, Object>`

Comment: @MickyLoo this appears to have worked, had no idea you could use extends in attribute declaration, thanks a lot!

Comment: @blvck_mvgic_dot_exe `Object` absolutely is, but `?` is not the same as `Object`, it's a wildcard representing "unknown class type, this can be literally anything".